# jQuery-UI Tabs... extremely simple - how to pass in params for add method()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm a bit of a jQuery newbie and I'm looking at the documentation for UI tabs.add()

http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/#method-add

The code example here doesn't show how to pass parameters to this add method... In fact, none of these examples seem to show how to pass in parameters.

Would anyone have any insight in to how to pass in these params?

Comment: `.tabs( "add", url, label );`

Comment: Works fantastically. Thanks! It really doesn't read like this is what you're supposed to do at all.

Comment: Yes I agree, the docs are not clear. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters as follows:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "add", url, label )
```